# Store email on session in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, session

So, today I make a simple login page with `AngularJS`.
And the purpose of this login that I want to store the email from `form` into `session`.

This is my login:

```
<label class="item item-input">
       <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.email" required>
</label>

<label class="item item-input">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password" required>
</label>
```

If we can refer to `PHP` programming language, you can use `$_SESSION['email']` and you store the `email` into the `session`.
I already read several article about `$SessionStorage` [Sample Example](http://ghost.scriptwerx.io/angularjs-sessionstorage)

What's the best approach to do store `session` in `AngularJS` ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to make service based on `window.sessionStorage` or `window.localStorage` to keep state information between page reloads. I use it in the web app which is partially made in AngularJS and page URL is changed in "the old way" for some parts of workflow. Web storage is supported even by IE8. Here is [angular-webstorage](https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage) for convenience.